# Using dynamic programming to count the number of permutations

Tags: algorithm, permutation, dynamic-programming

I have a string **A** of length **N**. I have to find number of strings (**B**) of length N that have **M (M<=N**) same characters as string **A** but satisfies the condition that **A[i]!=B[i]** for all i. Assume the characters that have to be same and the different ones are also given. What will be the recurrence relation to find number of such strings?

**Example**

123 is string A and M=1, and the character which is same is '1', and the new characters are '4' and '5'. The valid permutations are 451, 415, 514, 541. So it is a sort of derangement of 1 item of the given 3.

I am able to find the answer using inclusion-exclusion principle but wanted to know whether there is a recurrence relation to do the same?

Comment: To find a recurrence relation is a math question better ask here:http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EmmadKareem  Here i want to know how to apply DP to find number of solutions that is why i have asked it here

Comment: @user2094963 does A have all unique characters ?

Comment: @SHB can you please share your inclusion-exclusion approach with us ? i have trouble solving it by that method .

Answer (score 1):

Let us call g(M,N) the number of permutations satisfying your condition.

If M is 0, then the answer is N!

Otherwise, M>0 and consider placing the first character that is in string A.
There are M important positions corresponding to the places in the string where we are not allowed to place a certain character.

If we put our first character in one of these (M-1) important places (we cannot put it in position 1 due to the restriction), then we must take the place of one of the restricted characters, and so the number of restrictions reduces by 2 (1 for the character we place, and 1 for the character whose position we occupied).

If we put our first character in one of the N-M unimportant places, then we have only reduced the number of restrictions by 1.

Therefore the recurrence relation is:

```
g(M,N)=(M-1)g(M-2,N-1)+(N-M)g(M-1,N-1) if M>0
      =N! if M=0
```

For your example, we wish to calculate g(1,3) (1 character matches, total of 3 characters placed)

```
g(1,3)=(3-1)g(0,2)
      =(3-1).2!
      =4
```